# How to update Amazon S3's Redirection Rules via command line

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Amazon features a "Edit Redirection Rules" in the S3 management console:

[image: S3 console]

But **I wanted to automate that and update it via command line**, which I can't find. Even on Amazon's [documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html), it shows screenshots from the S3 interface, and there's no mention to any web API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The various AWS SDKs call this `putBucketWebsite`:

- CLI: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-website.html
- JavaScript: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putBucketWebsite-property
- PHP: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_putBucketWebsite